# Event counter in verilog

Tags: verilog

i'm a verilog beginner, i'm try to write a "event counter" on verilog.... this is my code, but it work only with "period" set to 16'b0000000000000001, if try set period to 16'b0000000000001000, result(out_event) is always '0'.
Someone can help me to fix it ?

```
module mymodule(
    input  wire          clk,
    input  wire             enable,
    input  wire             reset, 
    input    wire [15:0]        period,
    input    wire              in_event, 
    output reg                  out_event            
);

reg en = 1'b0; 
reg re = 1'b0;
reg [15:0] count = 16'b0000000000000000;
always @(posedge clk) en <= enable;
always @(posedge clk) re <= reset;


always @(in_event)begin


if(in_event == 1'b1)begin
if(re)begin
    count <= 0 ; 
    out_event <= 1'b0;
end else begin
    if(en) begin
        if(count == period-1)begin
            out_event <= 1'b1;
            count <= 0;
        end else begin
            count <=count + 1;
            out_event <= 1'b0;
        end
    end else begin
        out_event <= 1'b0;
    end
end

end else begin
    out_event <= 1'b0;

end

end 

endmodule
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Any flop assignment should be within your `always @(posedge clk)` block. Any comb logic should be in an `always @*` block (my preference) or `assign` statement. Your current logic uses complex latching, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The counter counts number of posedge of in_event wire. So, can you use *@(posedge in_event)*?

I simulated your code, providing a testbench to it.

I do not have much knowledge about hardware synthesis, but personally, I would suggest to write your logic based on edge/level of clock.

This code works completely well. Have a look at this [link](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/HK7).

You can configure various values of period in testbench, hope this will be helpful.

Comment: hi sharvil111 , thanks for your help, if use @(posedge in_event) counter work but with period set to 16'b0000000000000001 the out (out_event) is always set to 1'b1. i'm try to simulate code and it work, but when I synthesize it not work

Comment: @Foo As Greg mentioned, you are using a complicated latch setup to detect changes in the event. Most synthesis tool struggle with such descriptions and even when they succeed, there are likely a number of timing scenarios that will cause the circuit to behave in an undesired way. You should really change your design to use synchronous sampling rather than asynchronous latching.

Comment: Yaa, Although I don't know much about synthesis, I completely agree with Unn, regarding synchronous sampling making it a flop rather than a latch.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a test bench and the design for your problem and it works.

```
    `timescale 1s / 1s

module TB();
    reg clk;
    reg enable;
    reg reset;
    reg [15:0] period;
    wire out_event;
    wire [15:0] counter;

    initial begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        forever begin
            #1 clk = ~clk;
        end
    end

    stack_exch_code test (.clk(clk),
                          .enable(enable),
                          .reset(reset),
                          .period(period),
                          .out_event(out_event),
                          .tb_counter(counter)
                          );

    integer i;

    initial
        begin
            @(negedge clk) reset = 1'b1; enable = 1'b0; period = 16'h0000;
            @(negedge clk) reset = 1'b0; enable = 1'b1; period = 16'h00FF;
            for (i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i = i + 1)   begin
                @(negedge clk) period = period - 1; 
                @(posedge clk) $display ("Period = %h , Counter = %h, Out_Event = %b ", period, counter, out_event);
            end
            @(negedge clk) $finish;

        end

endmodule //TB

module stack_exch_code (input clk,
                        input enable,
                        input reset,
                        input [15:0] period,
                        //input inevent,
                        output reg out_event,
                        output [15:0] tb_counter
                        );

    // initialization doesnt matter in hardware, its not C or C++
    reg en;
    reg re;
    reg [15:0] count;

    always @ (posedge clk)  begin

        re <= reset;
        en <= enable;

    end

    always @ (posedge clk) begin

        if (re) begin

            count <= 16'h0000;
            out_event <= 1'b0;

        end 

        else if (en) begin

            if ((count == period - 1) && !(period == 16'h0000)) begin

                out_event <= 1'b1;
                count <= 16'h0000;

            end

            else if (!(period == 16'h0000)) begin

                count <= count + 1;
                out_event <= 1'b0;

            end

            else if (period == 16'h0000)

                out_event <= 1'b0;

        end
    end

    assign tb_counter = count;

endmodule //stack_exch_code
```